# terminal in pycharm can't recognize commands like "Poetry" but normal powershell can

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, python-poetry

I download poetry following [poetry doc](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-the-official-installer)in Windows. After the configuration of interpreter and poetry successfully in Pycharm,I tried to open terminal in pycharm and use commands like `poetry add` but error message occurs like this`Poetry : The "poetry" entry is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or runnable program. Check the spelling of the name, and if you include the path, make sure the path is correct and try again.`. I have included it in system path and it works fine in normal terminal or powershell.

Additionally,if I open Pycharm as Administrator,it works fine too.So I don't know why this will happen and how to fix it if I just open Pycharm without Administration.
OK,I guess this is related to system administrator but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

***Reason***

The reason for this is that you installed *&poetry*& for all users as administrator, so, you can execute it *only as administrator* (PyCharm terminal runs as non-admin).

***Solution***

Add directory with **poetry** executable (`C:\Users\\***YOUR_USER***\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts` by default) to `Path` environment variable for your user.